# how to divide two integers stored in variables then store the answer in an variable

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

```
from __future__ import division
import random,time
done = False
while not done:

    num1=random.randint(1,12)
    num2=random.randint(1,4)
    (num1 % num2 == num3)
    print (int(num3))

    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("your characters atrributes are",num3+10,)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    print("Would you like to quit? Y/N or y/n")
    restart = input(">>>")
    if restart == "Y" or restart == "y":
        done = True
    elif restart == "N" or restart == "n":
        done = False
    else:
        print("invaild the program will now terminate.")
        done = True
```

this is my code but i dont know how to store the result of (num1 % num2) into a variable called num 3 plz help me

Comment: `num3 = (num1 % num2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign it to a new variable

```
num3 = num1 % num2
```

Comment: thank you so much such a stupid mistake as well i was tearing my brains out trying to figure out what i had done wrong thank you so much so simple.

Answer (score 1):

`(num1 % num2 == num3)` is a Boolean value stating if the left of the `==` is equivalent to the right, which your code then ignores.

To *assign* a value, rather than check for equality use

```
num3 = num1 % num2 == num3
```

I also note your question title says you wish to *divide* two numbers.
Note that `/` is division while `%` is modulo:

```
>>> 6/3
2
>>> 6%3
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You've confused the "is it equal?" expression with the "I want this value to be stored *here*" expression.

- "Is it equal?"
  `num3 == num1 % num2;`
- "Assign the value"
  `num3 = num1 % num2;`

To a computer, ***each*** and ***every*** character is significant. You need to adopt this same mindset.